# Flexbox wont fill the content area

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Not sure if flexbox is the correct way of going about this, but basically I am looking for a 2 column flexbox.

In the first part I want to put random text in and the width of this part will adapt and become the same size as the text (whatever the text is).

The second part is a dotted hr line, which I want it to basically take up whatever space is remaining on the right-hand side.

Then there'll be a 16px gap in between. Is this the correct way to go about it? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for any help, much appreciated !

[what i want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYyk8.png)

**Edit: Thanks to everyone who answered, they all worked great tbh, but the solution I chose allowed for some extra flexibility. Again, appreciate everyones time, I don't have enough 'reputation' to upvote everybody! =)**

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #34363e;
}

.main {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h2-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0 32px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1136px;
  gap: 16px;
}

.h2-box {
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin: 0;
}

.hr-box {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 4px dotted #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h2-container">
      <div class="h2-box"><h2 class="">This is a title sentance</h2></div>
      <div class="hr-box"><hr></div>
    </div>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo leo, interdum quis auctor at, congue a justo. Donec accumsan nulla id fringilla vulputate. Ut sed mauris pellentesque, venenatis dui quis, consectetur nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `width: 100%` for `.h2-box`, and add `flex: 0 0 auto` instead.

Comment: What if the title is longer than 1 line? What is the expected behaviour? The 100% width is an issue on both boxes need to be removed, the dot box set flex grow to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issue with the implementation. You are heading to the right direction but just need a little bit of a tweak

First of all, remove the width 100% on the `h2-box` and the dot box.

Add `flex-grow: 1;` to the dot box and you are good. This will force the element to span the rest of the remaining width.

I am not sure what is expected if your title is more than 1 line long but something to think about for you.

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

Not sure if you meant to set inline-flex, but display flex works just fine.

`flex-direction` defaults to row so this is not needed

`flex-wrap` defaults to nowrap so this is also not needed

I am also unsure where you want the dotted line with regards to the title on the left but you can align that vertically with ease using `align-items`. I have used this in the example below to align the dots to the bottom using `align-items: flex-end;`

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #34363e;
}

.main {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h2-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 32px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1136px;
  gap: 16px;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin: 0;
}

.hr-box {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 4px dotted #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h2-container">
      <div class="h2-box"><h2 class="">This is a title sentance</h2></div>
      <div class="hr-box"><hr></div>
    </div>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo leo, interdum quis auctor at, congue a justo. Donec accumsan nulla id fringilla vulputate. Ut sed mauris pellentesque, venenatis dui quis, consectetur nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this way also allows me to go onto two lines (of text) if needed. I appreciate your time to help with this. This is the one I went for.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 100%;` on `.h2-box` and use either `flex: none;` or `flex: 0 0 auto;`.

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #34363e;
}

.main {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h2-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0 32px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1136px;
  gap: 16px;
  align-items: center;
}

.h2-box {
  flex: none;
  /*flex: 0 0 auto;*/
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin: 0;
}

.hr-box {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 4px dotted #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h2-container">
      <div class="h2-box"><h2 class="">This is a title sentance</h2></div>
      <div class="hr-box"><hr></div>
    </div>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo leo, interdum quis auctor at, congue a justo. Donec accumsan nulla id fringilla vulputate. Ut sed mauris pellentesque, venenatis dui quis, consectetur nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution... Choose what is better!

You can remove the  after your . You will have only the class .h2-box to make the style of your title.

After, you can use the styles for .h2-box :

```
  flex-basis: content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
```

The CSS Flexbox property flex-basis lets you specify the desired initial size of a flex item before downsizing or redistributing the remaining space in their Flexbox container.

So you'll have :

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #34363e;
}

.main {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.container {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h2-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding: 0 32px 16px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1136px;
  gap: 16px;
}

.h2-box {
  flex-basis: content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:100%;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin: 0;
}

.hr-box {
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 4px dotted #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h2-container">
      <h2 class="h2-box">This is a title sentance</h2>
      <div class="hr-box"><hr></div>
    </div>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo leo, interdum quis auctor at, congue a justo. Donec accumsan nulla id fringilla vulputate. Ut sed mauris pellentesque, venenatis dui quis, consectetur nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any widths from `.h2-container` down, `display: flex;` will take care of that. Control the size of the flexbox by setting widths, margins, and paddings on the parents, it will fill the parent width. You want the flexbox child that will fill the available space to have `flex-grow: 1;`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #34363e;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 64px 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.h2-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 32px;
  gap: 16px;
}

.h2-container .grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.h2-container h2 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.h2-container hr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-top: 4px dotted #cccccc;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 32px;
  margin: 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="h2-container">
      <div>
        <h2>This is a title sentence</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="grow">
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque leo leo, interdum quis auctor at, congue a justo. Donec accumsan nulla id fringilla vulputate. Ut sed mauris pellentesque, venenatis dui quis, consectetur nisl.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```